# Back transform raster values R

Tags: raster, raster-calculator

I have a raster in R and I just want to back-transform the values of the raster.

I know you have to use raster::calc but not sure how.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
#predicting model onto raster
r_pred <- raster::predict(model=rfcaret_1000, object=Ras1)

# back transform the values on a raster
back.transform <- exp(r_pred)
raster::calc(r_pred, back.transform)
```

I guess I could just do this in arc GIS pro but I'd like to know how it's done in R.

Comment: The `calc` function takes a function so, you can just pass `exp` directly eg. `calc(r_pred, fun=exp)`. Your back.transform is not a function, it would need to be something like; `back.transform <- function(x) { exp(x) }`